# Excel VBA Conditional Filter

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

simple VBA question.  I need a VBA subroutine that will filter my data based on a condition  (in this case, if what's in column C equals 11-Jun-12 [41071 in numeric form]) without looping through the whole data set.  I've looked a bit at filtering on the Internet but nothing seems to be quite what I want (or I just don't really understand what's going on).  To be clear, here's an example of what I want:

I want https://i.stack.imgur.com/23AqX.jpg

to go to https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2UK4.jpg.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just use auto filter? There is custom date filters (last option on date filters) that has choice of "does not equal" and a date picker

Comment: Well say I wanted to delete those rows altogether.  Is there no way of doing that other than looping through every row?

Comment: That I am not sure of. Probably not, but that is in no way a 100% certain answer.

Comment: You can easily delete the result of an AutoFilter.  So in this case you can AutoFilter for June 11, 2012 and delete the results.  Simply do `ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Delete` and the `ActiveSheet.ShowAllData` to show the things that didn't match the filter.

Comment: @JonKelly, could you write out the whole macro for me?  I've never worked with autofiltering in VBA so I'm not sure how to format it.

Comment: @JackRadcliffe I wrote it out in an answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the spreadsheet is set up as it appears in your screenshot here is what you can do

```
Sub DateFilter()
    'hide dialogs
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'filter for records that have June 11, 2012 in column 3
    ActiveSheet.Cells.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="6/11/2012"
    'deletes all matching rows
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Delete
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Jack Radcliffe,

Do you mean a simple autofilter, for example:

```
Sub SimpleColumnDateFilter1()

' Quick Recorded Macro
' Select a Column
' Activate Autofilter
' For a range C1 through the rest of C
' Autofilter such that the column will display dates not equal to 11/15/2012

Columns("C:C").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("C:C").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
    "<>11/15/2012", Operator:=xlAnd
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm trying to do.  However, this gives me an error and I'm not sure why.  Either way, Ross Larson (I think) cleared things up for me in the original post.  Thanks!

Comment: Jack, this basic example should function effectively now. I am simply working to make it more modular now. ~JOL